# SQL select data grouped by attr1 with criteria on attr2

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

Let's say I have table called `tbl` which looks like this:

```
attr1  attr2
  A      2
  A      1
  A      1
  B      1
  C      1
  C      3
```

I need to select only those data from `attr1` that for each of the same data in `attr1` have `1` or `2` in `attr2`.

So the result should be:

```
attr1
  A
  B
```

`C` should not be in result because in the group `C` one `attr2` has value `3`.

I'm doing this using SQL in MS Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `not exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select distinct attr1
from tbl t
where attr2 in (1, 2)
  and not exists ( select 1
                   from tbl
                   where attr1 = t.attr1
                     and attr2 not in(1, 2) )
```

Comment: Theer is some syntax error... I'm tryinig to find it and than will tell if it works

Comment: window pops out saying. Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'count(distinct attr2) = 2'

Comment: Sorry, still Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'count(distinct attr2)'

Comment: It seams to work when I add distinct in the first row, and change t1.attr1 to t.attr1 - Please fix it so that I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can count the instances of the allowed `attr2` and compare with the size of the group overall. If they are the same, all `attr2` values must have been "allowed":

```
SELECT attr1
FROM
(
    SELECT attr1,
    COUNT(*) AS group_count,
    SUM(IIF(attr2 IN (1, 2), 1, 0)) AS allowed_count
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY attr1
) AS allowed
WHERE allowed.group_count = allowed.allowed_count
```

I haven't got Access installed here (Linux!), so I'd be interested to see if I've got the syntax correct.

The subquery returns:

```
attr1 group_count allowed_count
A     3           3
B     1           1
C     2           1
```

And the main query just selects those values where `group_count` and `allowed_count` are equal:

```
attr1
A
B
```

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't work, I'm getting also "C" in result

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Window pops out saying: Your query does not include the specified expression 'attr1' as part of an aggregate function

Comment: Fixed, hopefully. Although I can't test it, so it might require a bit more tweaking. This is the right general idea though, I'd say.

Comment: It seams to work now. Unfortunately I already marked Suslov's answer - Thank you very much for your big effort!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, maybe you can try this new approach

Used NOT IN to substitute MINUS

```
SELECT DISTINCT attr1 FROM table1 WHERE attr1 NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT attr1 FROM table1 WHERE attr2 > 2 );
```

Comment: I was writting when you posted. And its not identical.

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't work, I'm getting also "C" in result

Comment: It doesn't work because there is no 'MINUS' in Access... I'm trying to replace it with something else...

Comment: It seams to work now. Unfortunately I already marked Suslov's answer - Thank you very much for your big effort!

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve what you need. 
Gets distinct lists of Attr1 and attr2. If Any Attr2 values are > 2 it excludes this row from the next level up.

```
Select 
ValueTable.attr1
From 
    (Select
    VAls.attr1,
    max(case when vals.attr2 > 2 then 2 else 1 End) as Attr2Count
    From(
        Select DISTINCT
        attr1, attr2
        from tbl)  VAls
    Group By VAls.attr1) as ValueTable
Where ValueTable.Attr2Count = 1
```